# Replace defaut authentification module in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

Suppose I've written my own authentication module implementing `IHttpModule`. It is not really done but there are good resources so I can figure it out.

There are also tutorials on how to add custom created module to `Web.config`. But how can I **replace** some default module ? That is how do I remove default authentication module from execution path ?

Can I just remove following lines from `Web.config`?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

If I remove them will the default authentication module still work ?

Of cause there is no real need to remove that module even if I don't use it... But it'll save some processor time and I'll feel better.

That was easy, not the hard part: can I replace `HttpContext` implementation? I have my own session class called `Session` and I don't want that `HttpSessionState` to be in `HttpContext`. I'd also like to replace `User` property of `HttpContext`. So I guess I need to create my own implementation of `HttpContext` and force my aplication to use it somehow.
How do I do it ?

Please feel free to answer any part of my question alone or all of them as you prefer.

Comment: What is the real problem you are solving by replacing authentication, session etc? What are the limitations in existing ASP.NET runtime? Perhaps you could look at something else other than ASP.NET?

Comment: Why not write your own custom `MemebershipProvider`?

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremat:There is no real limitation... I just don't like default membership system - it forces me to store passwords, security questions and some other thinks that I don't need (I'm using OpenID authentication). So it does not feel natural for my data model. Also it treats session as something that last while has their browser open... I want to keep it until they log of (like SO). And finally I want to have more sessions possible for one user. Considering all of this I decided that it will be clearer and easier to write my own session system rather then try to tweak existing

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Please read my previous comment - I hope it answers also your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<system.webServer> 
<modules> 
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />    
  <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />    
  <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />    
</modules> 
</system.webServer>
```

How about this?

Comment: Hmm now I realise that it might be hard to know that it works (modules are not used) Are you sure that this will work or can you suggest a way to check it ?

Comment: Is it really possible to remove `DefaultAuthentication` module this way? I tried and this yields an error message http://stackoverflow.com/q/17565717/57428

Comment: I think lockItem="true" in applicationHost.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `mode` to `None`. I would name your `HttpContext` something different.

Comment: What you mean by "I would name your HttpContext something different"?

Comment: @Dastro you could call it `CustomHttpContext`

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it. So I create new class `CustomHttpContext` inheriting from `HttpContext`? And than what ? How do I make it to be used instead of default `HttpContext` ?