# How do I get rid of DefaultAuthenticationModule module?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, httpmodule

I came to conclusion that I don't need `DefaultAuthenticationModule` in my application and I want to get rid of it. So I tried the following in web.config section responsible for modules:

```
<remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
```

and when I hit F5 in Visual Studio I see the following error message

> error ASPCONFIG: Special module of type 'DefaultAuthentication' cannot be added or removed manually.

So how do I get rid of the module?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it from IIS [refer](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Disabling), you can enable or disable the same for a particular website or application using methods mentioned in the link.